# How to get a prompt asking the user to enter his account details while login?

Tags: node.js, authentication, github, passport.js, github-api

I am implementing functionality that allows the user to SignUp and SignIn with GitHub using Passport.js and mongoose.
But every time I try to SignUp, it takes my default browser account and Signs me up using that account, rather I want to create a prompt that asks the user to enter his GitHub id and password so that he can choose which account he wants. How to do this? Here is my code below...

```
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ githubId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

app.get("/auth/github",
  passport.authenticate("github"));

app.get("/auth/github/callback",
  passport.authenticate("github", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/callback");
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to suggest an account to connect to in the Github Oauth2 authentication page, according to [Github Oauth documentation](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/#1-request-a-users-github-identity) :

```
GET https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize
```

You have the `login` field :

```
| Name  | Type    | Description |
|-------|---------|-------------|
| login | string  | Suggests a specific account to use for signing in and authorizing the app.
```

But this field is not parametered in [passport-github](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-github). You will need to override `OAuth2Strategy.prototype.authorizationParams` that comes from the [passport-oauth2](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2) repo [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L307-L321) :

```
/**
 * Return extra parameters to be included in the authorization request.
 *
 * Some OAuth 2.0 providers allow additional, non-standard parameters to be
 * included when requesting authorization.  Since these parameters are not
 * standardized by the OAuth 2.0 specification, OAuth 2.0-based authentication
 * strategies can overrride this function in order to populate these parameters
 * as required by the provider.
 *
 * @param {Object} options
 * @return {Object}
 * @api protected
 */
OAuth2Strategy.prototype.authorizationParams = function(options) {
  return {};
};
```

The implementation would be :

```
GitHubStrategy.prototype.authorizationParams = function(options) {
  return options || {};
};
```

and in the `authenticate` function pass the autorization arguments :

```
passport.authenticate('github', {
    login: req.body.login
})
```

Here is a complete example that override the authorizationParams and setting the `login` field to a value from an `input` :

```
var app = require('express')(),
    passport = require('passport'),
    GitHubStrategy = require('passport-github').Strategy,
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    github = require('octonode'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    session = require('express-session');

var config = {
    clientID: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    clientSecret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/github/callback'
};

var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: String, unique: true },
    access_token: String,
    refresh_token: String,
    name: String
}, { collection: "user" });

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

GitHubStrategy.prototype.authorizationParams = function(options) {
  return options || {};
};

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOne({ "id": id }, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
        clientID: config.clientID,
        clientSecret: config.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.callbackURL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        process.nextTick(function() {

            User.findOne({ id: profile.id }, function(err, res) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (res) {
                    console.log("user exists");
                    return done(null, res);
                } else {
                    console.log("insert user");
                    var user = new User({
                        id: profile.id,
                        access_token: accessToken,
                        refresh_token: refreshToken
                    });
                    user.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            return done(err);
                        return done(null, user);
                    });
                }
            })
        });
    }
));

function userLogged(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    res.redirect('/login');
}

app.use(session({ secret: 'somesecret' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/auth/github/callback',
    passport.authenticate('github', {
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        scope: ['user']
    }));

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.send(`
        <html>
        <body>
            <form action="/login" method="post">
                <span>Enter your preferred Github login</span>
                <input name="login" type="text" value=""/>
                <input type="submit" value="Connect"/>
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
    `)
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
    if (!req.body.login){
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    passport.authenticate('github', {
        login: req.body.login
    })(req,res,next);
});

app.get('/profile', userLogged, function(req, res) {

    var client = github.client(req.user.access_token);

    var ghme = client.me();

    ghme.repos((err, repos) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json({
                status: "error"
            });
        } else {
            console.log(repos);
            res.json({
                status: "ok",
                data: repos
            });
        }
    });
});

app.listen(8080)

console.log('go to http://localhost:8080/login')
```

You can find the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/13caa379cfc6c59743937e5eab88cb51)

The example above prompts the user :

[image: prompt user for login]

And in the Github authentication page, there is an hint at the top of the authentication page to login with the preferred account :

[image: github authentication page]